Windows Forms, .NET, C#, ApplicationSettings: how can I delete a userSetting?

First, if this has been answered previously, then my most abject apologies. I've searched and cannot find this issue addressed.
Using Visual Studio 2022 & C# to create a .NET Winforms application, I accidentally created a Location user setting in the ApplicationSettings section of a form's properties in design mode. I meant to create a text value instead (see screenshot).
I further fubared the situation by creating a Text value with the same name.
Now I can't find a way to delete them. There is no functionality to delete them from properties in design mode. I know the values are stored in the app.config and I tried manually deleting them from there but that didn't work. The values are obviously stored somewhere else but googling the issue has returned nothing at all.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Right-click "Location" > Reset

After digging around the project's folders in File Explored I found that the values were also stored in Settings.settings in the project's Properties folder. After I deleted them from there the issue was resolved.

Deleting solution files this way could damage it. Avoid doing this and follow the comment to your question.
